# Compile Bitmap into custom component

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created custom components on a C# Winforms Application. Some of these use Bitmaps that are being displayed. Today I have them added to the project as a resource, but I would like to  "compile" them into the component.

i.e.:
A custom exit button uses an X - Icon. How can I add it to the component? (Without adding it to the resources file of the project, if  it is possible.)

EDIT:

I use the bitmaps in custom Paint-Events. It would be a pain if the bitmap isn't found in the correct folder after the installation of the application.

Comment: Why you want to do that?

Comment: Because I want the component to be isolated from the rest. I was thinking maybe there are Resource files for single components, but apparently not?

Comment: After reading your edit i think what you want is an embedded resource inside the assembly. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to convert the desired resource to a byte array, include the byte array into the source code and again convert the resource to its initial format during runtime. A different option would be to embed the component in a dll.

Comment: Yes if this is not possible in a nice way, then I will embed it into a component...

Comment: In fact, I would consider my proposed solution as a 'non-nice' way.